# spring data JPA & spring data elasticsearch; No property index found for type?

Tags: spring, jpa, spring-data, spring-data-jpa, spring-data-elasticsearch

I'm unsure why this is happening! I've got a class that is used by spring data elasticsearch and spring data jpa, but when I try run my application I get an error.

```
Error creating bean with name 'articleSearch': 
Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is 
org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyReferenceException: 
No property index found for type Article!

Caused by: org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyReferenceException: 
No property index found for type Article!
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyPath.<init>(PropertyPath.java:77) ~[spring-data-commons-1.11.4.RELEASE.jar:na]
```

I've got the following application class:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableAsync
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"com.article.models", "com.user"})
public class ArticleApplication {
```

And the following elasticsearch config:

```
@Configuration
@EnableElasticsearchRepositories(basePackages = "com.article.search")
public class ElasticSearchConfiguration {
    @Resource
    private Environment environment;

    @Bean
    public Client client() {
        TransportClient client = new TransportClient();
        TransportAddress address = new InetSocketTransportAddress(environment.getProperty("elasticsearch.host"), Integer.parseInt(environment.getProperty("elasticsearch.port")));
        client.addTransportAddress(address);
        return client;
    }

    @Bean
    public ElasticsearchOperations elasticsearchTemplate() {
        return new ElasticsearchTemplate(client());
    }
}
```

This is how I've setup my model class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="article")
@Document(indexName="article", type="articles")

public class Article implements Serializable {
```

I've then got a package ***search*** that extends the ***elasticsearchrepository***, like so:

```
public interface ArticleSearch extends ElasticsearchRepository<Article, String> {
```

I'm trying to ***autowire*** the articlesearch class inside another service which is causing the error to occur:

```
@Autowired
ArticleSearch articleSearch;
```

What am I missing here?! I guess it's a bit more complex when trying to use data-jpa + data-elasticsearch.

Comment: can u show all the code of class Article?

Comment: It's a standard hibernate class with @ column annotations. I haven't added any elasticsearch annotations @xierui

Comment: I have seen the error before. I think you could check the methods in Repository or the queries  first. Some methods like "findByIndex" will case the error.

Comment: As the error log show 'articleSearch' , I think the method should be in 'articleSearch'. You would better show all of the code so I can see what's wrong with it.

Comment: Still no clue what's happening @xierui

Answer (score 4):

I found out why this was happening. I'm not sure why, but spring didn't seem to be picking up my `ElasticSearchConfiguration` configuration class!

So I simply moved all the contents from that and dumped it in my main application class (where all my other config is).

I also removed component scan & added the ***enablejparepository + enableelasticsearchrepository*** annotations to my main class. Here is what it looks like now:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableAsync
@EnableElasticsearchRepositories(basePackages = "com.article.search")
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = {"com.article.dao", "com.user.dao"})
public class ArticleApplication {
```